# Complex tryCatch in loop-R

Tags: r, loops, try-catch

I'm writing the code to get the data from Uncomtrade- an UN's database. Because the database has a usage limit of 100 enquiries/hour so I need to put a time out there. 
I want to write the code with tryCatch that will:

1. Automatically set programs to time out everytime the error for max limit appears
2. Rerun for the current level of i,j and k if a connection error orcurs

My current code still work though but I want to learn how to use tryCatch too
And also is there a way to get rid of the for loops. Can the apply family function be used here? 
                                       Thanks guys

```
 n=0
    a<-c()
 for (i in (1996:2014)) {
     for (j in c("0301","0302","0303","0304","0305","0306","0307","0308")) {
          for (k in c("704","116","360","418","458","104","608","702","764"))  {
             s2<-paste(i,j,k,sep="")
             a<-c(a,s2)
            print (s2)
            n<-n+1
            if(n<=100) {
          s1 <- get.Comtrade(r=k, ps=i, rg="2", cc=j, fmt="csv",px="H0")
        Sys.sleep (1)
           s1<-do.call(rbind.data.frame,s1)
           library(foreign)
           write.dta(s1,file=paste("D:/unTrade/",s2,".dta"))
           }
         else {
             print(n)
             print(s2)
             print("reset here")
             n=0
            Sys.sleep(3610)
         }
          }
        }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help you with the TryCatch(); I don't have the experience myself.

Regarding the for loops, this is one solution (although I think in these cases the for-loops are not that evil; vectorization really counts in all kinds of matrix operations etc).

```
dat <- expand.grid(i = 1996:1999, j = c("0301","0302","0303","0304","0305","0306","0307","0308"), k = c("704","116","360","418","458","104","608","702","764"))
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(i, j, k) %>% 
  do({
      cat('s1 <- get.Comtrade(r=', .$k, ', ps=', .$i, ', cc=', .$j, ', rg=\"2\", fmt=\"csv\",px=\"H0\")\n')
      flush.console()
      # return(s1)
  })
```

From your own code s1 (also) appears to be a data.frame, so in this case, the dplyr `do()` nicely glues all these data frames together.

HTH